# mysql Nodejs connection.query like operator error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to fetch a bunch of values entered by the user using mysql like operator

In my get route in Nodejs I have

```
 console.log(req.query.key)
 pool.query("select FirstName from users where FirstName like %'" + req.query.key +"%'"
```

In my debug console I get

dav

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '%'dav%'

I just ran this query in mysql workbench and it is working properly over there

```
select FirstName from users where FirstName like '%dav%'
```

MySQL Workbench returns

David

I am not sure why I get the error in Nodejs

**Edit 1:**

```
I am using the `mysql` package
```

**app.js**

```
    const mysql= require('mysql');

    const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: keys.connection.host,
    user: keys.connection.user,
    password:keys.connection.password,
    database:keys.connection.database,
})
```

I am sure there is not issues with my connection because my other routes are working properly without error

Comment: What package are you using to run this query?  I'm not familiar with "pool".

Comment: It's the mysql package. I edited my question to include the package setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the quote character *before* the first `%`, not after it.

```
pool.query("select FirstName from users where FirstName like '%" + req.query.key +"%'"
```

Comment: Sorry, I was working late. My answer was in my question. Thank you